# MS Access Field splitting

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to split following data field in separate columns like using ":" separator,

**Actual Data**

```
DSLAM name:Port address 
M301-41-301_DDOW3:1-0-7-1
```

**Result**

```
DSLAM name  Port address
M301-41-301_DDOW3   1-0-7-1
```

I am using following script but having missing operator syntax error.

```
UPDATE 14052017 SET

NodeName= left(DSLAMname:Port address, InStr( DSLAMname: Port address, ":") -1),
PortAddress= Mid(DSLAMname:Port address, InStr( DSLAM name: Port address, ":") +1);
```

please point out the mistake here or a better solution

Comment: Start by using square brackets around field names: `NodeName= left([DSLAMname:Port address], InStr( [DSLAMname: Port address], ":") -1)`. Any field in Access that includes spaces or special characters should be enclosed by square brackets.

Comment: I used square brackets and now no syntex error, but now it is asking for "Enter Parameter Value" against "DSLAMname:Port address". What is the reason when Parameter value is being asked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make a Function:

```
Public Function SplitValue(ByVal value_ As Variant, ByVal index As Long) As String
    If Not IsNull(value_) Then SplitValue = Split(value_, ":")(index)
End Function

'....

UPDATE 14052017 SET
NodeName= SplitValue([DSLAMname:Port address], 0),
PortAddress= SplitValue([DSLAMname:Port address], 1);
```